# Handle Many To One Exception in Sonata Admin Bundle

Tags: symfony, sonata-admin

I have 2 tables with a ManyToOne Relationship.

```
class Parent
{
  /**
     * @var integer $id
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer", nullable=false)
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="IDENTITY")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     *
     * @ORM\OneToMany(cascade={"persist"},targetEntity="Child", mappedBy="parent")
     */

    private $child;

  // getters and setters
}

class child{

     /**
     * @var integer $id
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer", nullable=false)
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="IDENTITY")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var Parent
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(cascade={"persist"},targetEntity="Parent")
     * @ORM\JoinColumns({
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="parent_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     * })
     *
     */
    private $parent;

   // getters and setters

}
```

1. Now how do I handle an exception generated when a row of the parent table is Deleted?
2. How do I display the Message in Sonata Admin Generator Form?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1: Now how do I handle an exception generated when a row of the parent table is Deleted?

Sol: The following steps should do the trick

1. OverRide the CRUDController provided by sonata admin bundle. Make sure the overridden CRUDController is in the same location as the original CRUDController. ie.YourProject/AdminBundle/Controller/CRUDController.php
2. Copy the deleteAction and batchActionDelete from the original controller to your Overridden controller. ie

   public function deleteAction($id)
       {

   ```
       $id     = $this->get('request')->get($this->admin->getIdParameter());

       $object = $this->admin->getObject($id);

      if (!$object) {
           throw new NotFoundHttpException(sprintf('unable to find the object with id : %s', $id));
       }

       if (false === $this->admin->isGranted('DELETE', $object)) {
           throw new AccessDeniedException();
       }

       if ($this->getRequest()->getMethod() == 'DELETE') {

        try {

               $this->admin->delete($object);

               $this->get('session')->setFlash('sonata_flash_success', 'flash_delete_success');

           } catch (\Exception $e) {

               $this->get('session')->setFlash('sonata_flash_error', sprintf('Cannot Delete because it has Dependeny'));
           }
            return new RedirectResponse($this->admin->generateUrl('list'));
          }

       return $this->render($this->admin->getTemplate('delete'), array(
           'object' => $object,
           'action' => 'delete'
       ));
   }
   ```
3. The try catch block should take care of the rest.

2.How do I display the Message in Sonata Admin Generator Form?

sol: The message in the cache block will be displayed in the sonata admin bundle form

ie.

```
try {

                    $this->admin->delete($object);

                    $this->get('session')->setFlash('sonata_flash_success', 'flash_delete_success');

                } catch (\Exception $e) {

                    $this->get('session')->setFlash('sonata_flash_error', sprintf('Cannot Delete because it has Dependeny'));
                }
```

NOTE . Make sure you import all the necessary files